# Celery AttributeError : 'download_all' object has no attribute 'location'

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I want to create a progress bar for my project. I have a class and this class has some functions. Especially, one of them takes a long time (`def download_all`) and this is my main reason for wanting to create a progress bar.

I successfully set up celery, celery-progress, etc. and they work all fine. My problem is this: I want to integrate the progress bar to `download_all` function. I

It gives an error:  AttributeError: 'download_all' object has no attribute 'location'
I am sure that this error is because of the celery task because when I run it without celery, it works.

This is my code. How can I do it?
**views.py**

```
def setup_wizard(request):
   ...
   task = (functions.myClass(n_username, n_password,
                                          n_url, n_port, db_password,
                                          username=request.user.username)).delay(5)

   task_id = task.download_all(request.user.username, setup.nsername, setup.n_password,
                                      setup.n_url, setup.ns_port, setup.db_password,
                                      username=request.user.username).task_id

    # in task_id download_all parameters, I had to user request.user.username instead of "self" parameter.
   ...
   context = {
     ...
     'task_id':task_id
    }
```

**functions.py**

```
class myClass():

    def __init__(self, n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password, username):
        self.location = zt_dosya_url
        self.static_fields = {}
        self.download_all(n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password)
        self.send(username)
        ...
     @shared_task(bind=True)
     def download_all(self, n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password):
        if not os.path.exists(self.location):
            os.mkdir(self.location)
        else:
            shutil.rmtree(self.location, ignore_errors=True)
            os.mkdir(self.location)

         ...
         for s in scans:
                i = 0
                scanner.scan_name = s['name']
                ...
                progress_recorder.set_progress(i + 1, len(scans), f'On iteration {i}')
                ...
                i += 1
```

**traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/operasyonmerkezi/konfigurasyon

Django Version: 3.2.7
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'dashboard',
 'accounts',
 'logs',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_apscheduler',
 'easy_timezones',
 'django_celery_results',
 'celery_progress']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\dashboard\views.py", line 128, in setup_wizard
    task = (functions.myClass(setup.n_username, setup.n_password,
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\dashboard\functions.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.download_all(self, n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\celery\local.py", line 188, in __call__
    return self._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py", line 389, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\dashboard\functions.py", line 147, in download_all
    progress_recorder.set_progress(i + 1, len_scans, description="Downloading")
  File "C:\Users\edeni\Desktop\hawkdragon\myvenv\lib\site-packages\celery_progress\backend.py", line 46, in set_progress
    self.task.update_state(

Exception Type: AttributeError at /operasyonmerkezi/konfigurasyon
Exception Value: 'myClass' object has no attribute 'update_state'
```

Comment: You should decorate a function using the shared_task decorator (not a class). Decorate the download_all function using shared_task(bind=True) & try again.

Comment: @Crash0v3rrid3 I made some changes can you look at again the same error

Comment: Well, what's the result of your execution?

Comment: @Crash0v3rrid3 It doesn't work. 'download_all' object has no attribute 'location'

Comment: Even after moving the decorator?

Comment: @Crash0v3rrid3 actually when I ask question the decorato was here but I write wrong. So yes, still the same

Comment: Remove bind=True from the shared_task call. That tells celery to bind the task object with the task function.

Comment: Now it says myClass object has no attribute 'update_state'
````venv\lib\site-packages\celery_progress\backend.py, line 46, in set_progress````
 and ````self.task.update_state````

Comment: Attach the traceback of the new exception

Comment: @Crash0v3rrid3 I added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238957/discussion-between-crash0v3rrid3-and-edche).